# Regular_expression PHP

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

How Do I find the name of the page title from `$_SERVER['php_self']`? 
Let's say the `$_SERVER` shows my page like this: `/application/mysite/signup.php`. How can I select the page title `signup` ?

Comment: To strictly answer your question: `.*\/(.*)\.php`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
echo basename($_SERVER['php_self'], '.php');
```

or [`pathinfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$pathInfo = pathinfo($_SERVER['php_self']);
echo $pathInfo['filename'];
```

Comment: +1 because it is a great answer and I can give you an Elightened Badge good sir! :)